# Windows Console API Functions reattach to the console

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am wanting to implement functionality for

dir | editor

This requires that the text be read from GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE )

and then that the standard input be closed and standard input be attached to the keyboard.

I have found no way to attach the current window to the keyboard but I can create a new window and then use that.

Unfortunately I have not been able to control the size of that window.

The code I am using is below but currently I get

SCSBerr 87.

The app runs but initially it looks like this

[Window initially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o7LI.png)

When the window is resized it looks like this

[Window Resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fl90.png)

The Environment is Visual Studio 6.0 on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 (same result).

```
{ BOOL rc;
  RECT rect;
  SMALL_RECT sr;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO sbi;
  COORD sz;
  char buf[80];

  if (term.t_nrowm1 >= csbiInfoO.dwSize.Y)
    term.t_nrowm1 = csbiInfoO.dwSize.Y - 1;
  if (term.t_ncol > csbiInfoO.dwSize.X)
    term.t_ncol = csbiInfoO.dwSize.X;
//if (term.t_ncol > 80)
//  term.t_ncol = 80;
   
  sr.Left = 0+0;
  sr.Top = 0+3;
  sr.Right = 0+term.t_ncol-1;
  sr.Bottom = 0+term.t_nrowm1-3/* say */;
  sz.X = term.t_ncol;
  sz.Y = term.t_nrowm1+1;

//sprintf(buf, "RowM1 %d Col %d", term.t_nrowm1, term.t_ncol);
//mbwrite(buf);

  origwin = GetForegroundWindow();
 
  GetWindowRect(origwin, &rect); 

  g_ConsoleOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  if (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(g_ConsoleOut, &sbi) == 0)
    flagerr("SCGCSBIErr %d");
#if 1
  FreeConsole();
//if (AttachConsole((DWORD)-1) == 0)
//   flagerr("SCAC%d");

  if (AllocConsole() == 0)
    flagerr("SCAllocErr %d");
#endif
  g_ConsoleIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  if (g_ConsoleIn < 0)                                      /* INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE */
    flagerr("Piperr %d");
  g_ConsoleOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );

//flagerr("HConsoleOut %d", g_ConsoleOut);

  if (SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(g_ConsoleOut, sbi.dwMaximumWindowSize) == 0)
    flagerr("SCSBerr %d");
  if (SetConsoleWindowInfo(g_ConsoleOut, true, &sr) == 0)
    flagerr("SCWIEerr %d");

  //SetConsoleTitle("Debug Window");

  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(MyHandlerRoutine, true);

{ HWND mwh = GetForegroundWindow();
  if (mwh == NULL)
    flagerr("MwHerr %d");

{ Cc cc = SetWindowPos(mwh, HWND_TOP, 10,10,
//           ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - (rc.right - rc.left)) / 2),
//           ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) / 2), 
                                 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE /*| SWP_NOACTIVATE*/); 
  if (cc == 0)
    flagerr("SwPerr %d");
}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have found no way to attach the current window to the keyboard

The interactive console's buffer is available as [CONIN$](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles), even when the standard handle is redirected. The following snippet waits until the standard input stream ends (via Ctrl-Z, or end of piped input), then repoints `stdin` to `CONIN$`.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char sz[256];

    while(fgets(sz, sizeof(sz), stdin))
        fputs(sz, stdout);
    printf("finished stdin\nstarting conin$\n\n");

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };
    HANDLE h = CreateFile("CONIN$",
                          GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                          FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                          &sa,
                          OPEN_EXISTING,
                          0, NULL); // ignored
    if(h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || !SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, h))
        return GetLastError();

    int n = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)h, _O_RDONLY | _O_TEXT);
    if(n == -1 || _dup2(n, _fileno(stdin)))
        return errno;

    printf("type a short string\n");
    if(scanf("%s", sz) == 1)
        printf("read '%s' ...done\n", sz);

    // todo: cleanup
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Questaware if this answer does work for you, you could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.